# Como criar um link para visualizar arquivos no servidor?

Tags: html, link

Eu tenho uma pasta que se chama userFiles na minha raiz.
Quando o admin abrir a tela ele vera uma lista contendo o nome do usuário e uma coluna com o link para visualizar o arquivo que aquele usuário fez o upload previamente.

Ou seja, eu quero que quando o ADMIN click no link ele possa ter acesso ao arquivo.

Estou seguindo o que vi nesse [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page) mas não está dando certo.

```
<a href="file:///C:\Site1\fileroot\br\userFiles\user1.csv">Arquivo</a>
```

O link é criado mas quando faço clik em cima do link nada acontece.

Alguem sabe onde estou errando?

### UPDATE

Nota: Estou num servidor local, IIS win7.
Inseri o atributo download na tag e ele me envia um download mas com erro.

```
<a href="file:///../fileroot/br/userFiles\user1.csv" download>Arquivo</a>
```

Tentei remover tbm a palavra file e é esse o erro que estou recebendo:Server problem. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### UPDATE 2

Achei o ponto do problema mas não sei como resolver.

Esse é o meu código:

```
<a  href="../fileroot/userFiles/t1.csv" download>Download t1.csv - ok</a>
```

Essa linha de código funciona SOMENTE se eu colocar manualmente o arquivo t1.csv dentro do diretório userFiles.

Se eu faço uma cópia do arquivo e nomeio t2.csv e em seguida uso o site para fazer o upload do arquivo t2.csv ele é passado para o diretório userFiles, como deveria.
Copio o código HTML e mudo o nome do arquivo pata t2.csv.

```
<a  href="../fileroot/userFiles/t2.csv" download>Download t2.csv - ok</a>
```

Aqui ele não funciona mais e laça a mensagem de erro que se vê na foto: Failed-Server problem.

Como se algo acontecesse com o arquivo durante o processo de upload (quando o usuário manda para o servidor).

Alguma idéia?

Comment: Seus arquivos estão no servidor? O caminho é mesmo o disco C:??

Comment: Então, foi o que vi no post. Achei estranho tbm

Comment: É que provavelmente no post o cara esta utilizando em servidor local, você tem que colocar o caminho do seu arquivo. Tenta colocar tipo: "/wwwroot/caminho_ate_o_arquivo/arquivo.csv", isso se seu arquivo for .csv e se seu servidor tiver essa pasta wwwroot, que pode variar de acordo com o servidor. É a pasta que esta seu site no servidor

Comment: Qual erro que aparece?

Comment: Esse que eu postei na foto. Veja no rodapé. O último erro foi Failed server problem. Acho que tem algo com permissóes do IIS.  Acabei de rodar uma outra página e recebi esse erro: `HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.`

Comment: Pessoal fiz um update...